# How to read text from pdf into list in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. I am trying to read text from pdf and store that into list. I am able to read the docx file and and storing the text into list.
But for pdf I am unable to do so. please help.

Below is the code snippet which I am using to read text from pdf file

```
def convertPDFToText(path):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'  # 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, codec=codec, 
                           laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    password = ""
    maxpages = 0
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, 
                                  password=password, caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=True):
    interpreter.process_page(page)
    fp.close()
    device.close()
    string = retstr.getvalue()
    retstr.close()
    return string
```

Comment: I don't understand why this question is down voted. Please mention the reason for down voting.

Answer (score 0):

pdfminer has  working samples about how you do this.

https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six

Comment: I am unable to find any such working samples in https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six . Can you please tell me where it is?

Comment: @Aviru , sorry for the delay. But i usually go to the tests folder and then search for examples in how to use the librarry.